# How to configure web.config for multiple virtual applications in Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, iisnode

I am trying to have multiple Node.js applications working in parallel in the same Azure App Service instance. I tried making a virtual application per Node.js app but I constantly get a server error (code 500). I use ZipDeploy or Azure DevOps to deploy my applications.

I suspect the problem might be that the *web.config* files associated with my applications is incorrect.

Here are some details on my setup:

In the *Application settings* menu of my App Service instance, I went to the *Virtual applications and directories* settings and put the following:

```
/                         site\wwwroot                        Application x
/mysite1                  site\wwwroot\mysite1                Application x
/mysite2                  site\wwwroot\mysite2                Application x
```

My *wwwroot* directory looks as follows. To make sure the problem doesn't come from the code itself, I used the same Node.js application for all three:

```
index.html
server.js
scripts
web.config (*)
----- mysite1
      |----- index.html
      |----- server.js
      |----- scripts
      |----- web.config (**)
----- mysite2
      |----- index.html
      |----- server.js
      |----- scripts
      |----- web.config (***)
```

I use the default web.config file ([provided by Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps)) for the three of them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Using this configuration, I can reach *https://myappservice.azurewebsites.net/* without issue but *https://myappservice.azurewebsites.net/mysite1* only returns a server error.

I tried taking off the handlers from the *web.config* files in subdirectories (** and ***) as instructed in similar questions but to no avail.

What is the correct configuration for these three files? I suppose the rewrite rules need to be adjusted but I am unsure what is the exact expected value for each.

Comment: You could accept your reply as answer to close this issue:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to pinpoint the exact problem through the IIS logs (*/LogFiles/W3SVC.../* on Kudu) :

```
ModuleName="RewriteModule", Notification="SEND_RESPONSE", HttpStatus="500", HttpReason="URL Rewrite Module Error.", HttpSubStatus="52", ErrorCode="Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
 (0x800700b7)", ConfigExceptionInfo="\\?\D:\home\site\wwwroot\mysite1\web.config ( 16) :Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'rule' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'NodeInspector'
"
```

What needed to be changed were the handler and rule names in the child web.config file, so that they wouldn't clash with the names in the parent web.config file. Everything works correctly now.

Comment: I have tried following the same but getting 404 not found in virtual apps. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

You could change Virtual applications and directories settings as below:

```
/                         site\wwwroot                Application x
/mysite1                  site\mysite1                Application x
/mysite2                  site\mysite2                Application x
```

When you deploy with zipdeploy or DevOps, the site name and Destination URL is like below:

[image]

For more details you could refer to [Deploying multiple virtual directories to a single Azure Website](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/).

Comment: Thanks, but ZipDeploy and DevOps do not show the same screen as Visual Studio. In both cases you can still deploy to virtual directories through different ways, but the problem with the web.config files remains.